# Weird unexplainable function behaviour

Tags: solidity, remix, dapps

I am trying to create a smart contract which stores a list of users. Further, a joint account can be created between any two users. My code is given below. edge_list maps each of the linked neighbours to the balance on that link.

```
contract MyContract{
struct User{
    uint user_id;
    string user_name;
    mapping(uint=>uint) edge_list;
}

mapping(uint=>User) users;

function registerUser(uint user_id, string user_name) public{
        users[user_id] = User(user_id, user_name);
}

function createAcc(uint user_id_1, uint user_id_2) public{
        users[user_id_1].edge_list[user_id_2] = 50;
        users[user_id_2].edge_list[user_id_1] = 50;
}
```

When I create two users with ID 1 and 2, and try to create an account between them, I would expect `users[1].edge_list[2]=50` and `users[2].edge_list[1]=50`. But for some reason the output I see is `users[1].edge_list[2]=50` and `users[2].edge_list[2]=50`. [I am calling registerUser(1), registerUser(2) and createAcc(1,2)]
I've been trying to figure it out for the past 6 hours but haven't understood. Is there something I am missing?

[image]

Comment: I replicated your code using solc <0 .7.0 (mandatory to be able to make assignement with nested mappings like you do) and saw no strange behavior... `users[1][2] == 50,`  `users[1][1] == 0` `users[2][1] == 50` and `users[2][2] == 0` are all true.

Comment: @hroussille I am using the remix IDE and solidity 0.4.25. Still getting the wrong output. I've added an image to the question. Should I use a different version or something?

Comment: what is allUsers ? it's the name of your mapping in your code maybe ?  It doesn't match the code you provided here. I personally added the following function to check :     function getUsers() public view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        return (users[1].edge_list[2], users[1].edge_list[1], users[2].edge_list[1], users[2].edge_list[2]);
    }